# How to Use the run tool in Tool windows

Tags: android, android-studio

My run tool of Tool windows in view is grayed out and I have no idea as to what to do to be able to use it[image: here in windows I want the run tool(Alt+4)to become visible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Run tool window displays output generated by your application. If you are running multiple applications, each one is displayed in a tab named after the [run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration.html) applied.

It highlight when any application in your IDE is in running state.

Answer (score 3):

The Run Command is disabled when the Gradle is not built correctly.

Try Invalidating the cache.

Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

Also, please attach the screenshot for Event Log, if above steps doesn't work for you.

Comment: To re-enable the Run Command (it was greyed out in View -> Tool Windows. I had also lost the "Run" tab in the bottom panel of windows), invalidating the cache and restarting AS didn't quite work for me. Instead, I had to hit Run -> Run <My app/project or Tests>

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Very noob of me to ask. I should have tried a little harder. opened the gradle and pressed ctrl+shift. it worked